# How to install numpy and matplotlib for python 3.4 on win7 64 bit machine

Tags: windows, numpy, matplotlib

I'm want to immigrate to python from matlab. I need to load and process data. I successfully installed V3.4 on a 64 bit win 7 machine. Where to download form, and how to install numpy and matplotlib? (I'm new so pls start from scratch).

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I like [WinPython](http://winpython.sourceforge.net/), which doesn't seem to support 3.4 yet, but the cool thing in town now is Continuum's [Anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads#py34).

Comment: Now I'm getting the picture of this Python community, thanks a lot for the useful info!